# Target multiple controls with a single storyboard to change styles for the snapped view state

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML page for a Windows Store application that has a dozen or so buttons within a Grid. They all have the same style defined. E.g.

```
<Button Content="1"  Name="btn1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource PadButtonStyle}"/>
<Button Content="2"  Name="btn3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource PadButtonStyle}"/>
<Button Content="3"  Name="btn4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource PadButtonStyle}"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

When the page switches from the full screen landscape view state to snapped I'd like to use a storyboard to change the style of all these buttons from PadButtonStyle to SnappedPadButtonStyle.

Using something like the following I can do this, but I'd need to create one ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames for every button.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
    <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btn1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPadButtonStyle}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Is there some way to collectively change the styles for all the buttons without referencing each individually?

Comment: Perhaps you could name the storyboard, and add the object animations using code behind? I know this is a bit ugly though :/

Comment: I'm open to using code if need be. I was hoping I could do something declarative in the XAML. E.g. All the things that had style A now have style B when snapped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a way to apply storyboards to a collection of controls.

However, it occurred to me that a better solution would be to create an entirely separate Grid to contain just the controls required for the snapped view and then apply the required styles directly in the XAML.

Then all I need to do in the Snapped VisualState is collapse one Grid and make the other visible. It requires a number of more controls in the XAML, but greatly reduces the storyboard requirements.